# Mac OS change command to control key

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

is there any way to change the use of command key to control, somewhat globally in the system? for example instead of cmd+S, to use ctrl+S, but everywhere in the system

Comment: If you're new to the Mac, I recommend against trying to make the Mac like Windows or Linux or whatever you were coming from. Make yourself do it the Mac way and pretty soon your brain will automatically switch between platforms with ease.

Comment: i'm actually using mac in vmware, i'm not a regular mac user and probably never will be

Comment: VMware Fusion has an option to re-map keys before they're sent to the VM. Maybe your VMware software has a similar option. We don't generally provide support for Mac OS X on non-Apple hardware though, since this violates Apple's end user license.

Comment: I'm a long-time Mac user, but I used this tip to configure my Windows keyboard to be more Mac-like. Thanks!

Comment: Another downside... Command+Arrow buttons will swap based on application, not globally... Best solution is really to do a hardware swap.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can switch the modifier key associations in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard » Modifier Keys…*:

[image]

Comment: While this might be useful in the short term or when you're only rarely using a Mac, you're better off learning how to use it as intended. This will enable you to switch Macs without lengthy reconfiguration, and you won't get it to work exactly like Windows or Linux anyway -- the little differences will probably just annoy you, eating up your time as you look for solutions.

Comment: Perhaps you are right, but then again every other OS is using ctrl+c,v,s to copy/paste/save. It would be nice to have at least those work on OS X.

Comment: On a proper Mac, I'd keep the default settings. But if you are using a Hackintosh (or just a windows style keyboard), the symbols on the keyboard are pretty confusing. It works wonders to usability to swap command and ctrl there.

Comment: yep, and some keyboards have very awkwardly placed windows keys, so ctrl remapping is really a must. As jdm said, the assertion that *you shouldn't do this* only applies to bona-fide mac accessory setup.

Comment: @DanielBeck you think this is "lengthy"? it took 30 seconds...

Comment: It's even more of a pain for users switching between OS on multiple machines regularly. My dual-booted mac uses the exact same keyboard. It's a productivity killer to be pressing the wrong shortcuts all the time.

Comment: @DanielBeck: I strongly doubt that the main motivation for switching the keys is to be able to use control instead of command. IMHO the reason for doing this is to 'reposition' the command key on the very bottom left, so as to be able to use if without looking at the keyboard. I will never understand this key placement from Apple's perspective, as I think many users never use the control key at all. 
I once had a Lenovo laptop where the Fn key was on the bottom left instead of the Ctrl, and it drove me nuts until I found a way to switch. No one would ever place Esc anywhere but top left.

Comment: @MaxiMus "_No one would ever place Esc anywhere but top left_" It's been done, [exhibit 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:DEC_VT100_terminal.jpg), [exhibit 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Adm3aimage.jpg) (and that's just keyboards that actually had the key). The latter apparently even is why Esc is so prominent in the vi editor, and many people remap Esc onto the caps lock key. Re Ctrl/Cmd, personally I like no longer having to contort my left little finger for keyboard shortcuts, and instead can use the thumb fairly easily for almost all shortcuts.

Comment: This is one of the things that drive me nuts. I'm using a hackintosh for work with a standard windows keyboard, and using the windows key as control makes my fingers stress. After a while it hurts. I tried using Karabine, but just a swap between control and command wouldn't do the trick. e.g in terminal, the termination command is Control + C, but when you swap keys it changes to Command + C. So is not just only swapping, we would need some kind of system autoconfigurator that changes all these key layouts or just buy keyboards with the correct layout.

Comment: Note: If you use multiple keyboards (such as an external keyboard), you need to select the keyboard at the top before setting the modifier keys.  Otherwise it won't work.  (This also allows you to have cmd and ctrl mapped normally for your laptop keyboard, and mapped backwards for your external windows-friendly keyboard.)

Answer (score 13):

[KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) can be used for more tweaks like this. Also see [TextMate Blog » Key bindings for switchers](http://blog.macromates.com/2005/key-bindings-for-switchers) for changing the behavior of page up, page down, home and end.

Comment: KeyRemap4MacBook is the best because it takes care of double switching.

Answer (score 7):

[Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/) A powerful and stable keyboard customizer for macOS.