# Mac OS X change of modifier keys depending on current application

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I would like to swap the control key with the command key, but only while in a given application.

I saw [this](https://superuser.com/questions/250611/mac-os-change-command-to-control-key) but it works globally.

[This](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/cocoa-text.html) seems also to work on a global level, although I am not as sure.

Answer (score 2):

[KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) did the trick wonderfully.