# Shortening time to copy and paste on Mac

Tags: macos, mac

When I use the copy and paste functionality of my Mac (command+c, command+v)

The machine takes a relatively long time to actually paste the clipboard contents onto the screen.

OS X 10.9.5

[image]

Is this normal? Is there a fix for this?

Comment: No, this is not normal, but we need more information in order to determine what is going on there. Like instantly memory use, and possible open apps that use huge amount of memory like safari or creative suite.

Comment: Mavericks was always good until you got into paging & compression, then slowed to a crawl. SSD rather than HD helps. Posting details of Activity Monitor's Memory tab would help.

Comment: yeah I am on a HDD not SDD MacBook Pro. That might be part of the issue. I am not running any memory intensive programs, but the paste function is really slow. I literally dread every time I have to paste something. I am a software developer so this is a real problem. Also why the downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this 'delay' problem by remapping my command and control keys.

Using the command key seemed to be causing unresponsiveness; so I remapped the keys switching the control key with the command key and pasting is now much faster than before.

Another reason why the copy/paste was slower, I believe, is that I installed a clipboard tool that saved clipboard items into a history. That I think was the primary culprit, but remapping keys also is a good idea for productivity.

Comment: would you like to be more specific ? If you really found some solution to that, it could be useful as Q&A.

Comment: hi Dimitris, how do you want me to be more specific? I can show exactly how I mapped the keys. The amount of downvotes on this question is dismaying and makes me not want to participate.

Comment: to be more specific, I followed this solution http://superuser.com/questions/250611/mac-os-change-command-to-control-key