# can shortcut be configured to paste with both control-v and command-v on mac?

Tags: macos

Since I transition between Mac/Windows/Linux daily I use settings->keyboard->"app shortcuts" to map my paste command to control-v instead of command-v, which works in most apps

The problem is certain websites (for example jsfiddle.net) does not honor the remapping, so on that site and I cannot use EITHER control-v or command-v to paste, forcing me to have to right click my mouse to paste.

For these cases, I would prefer to not lose command-v, and to be able to paste with EITHER control-v or command-v instead of having to trade away command-v to use control-v to paste (same goes for the copy command control-c/command-c as well)

is that possible?

Comment: I'd just learn the difference & not try to force any OS to do this. 'Vive la difference'. It's easier in the long run. You can swap the modifier keys in prefs, but it's a swap for everything, it still won't give you both options - see https://superuser.com/questions/250611/mac-os-change-command-to-control-key?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) and these [settings](https://github.com/rux616/karabiner-windows-mode). You can then use either ctrl or cmd for copy and paste. There are many more improvements, such as sensible home/end key actions! It's also configured not to interfere with ctrl-c in a shell or with IDE's mappings.